# Encode an image from the clipboard as base64 in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, base64

I have a JavaFX app where I'm trying to read an image from the clipboard and encode it as base64 string to save it in a database (small screenshots with up to 100x100px). There are several examples to read an image file as byte array, but I can't find a method to get the bytes of a clipboard image. I tried this:

```
var image = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getImage();
    if(image != null) {

        int w = (int)image.getWidth();
        int h = (int)image.getHeight();
        byte[] buf = new byte[w * h * 4];

        image.getPixelReader().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(), buf, 0, w * 4);

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buf);
    }

    return null;
```

But the String content that I get from this can't be decoded in any format (using several online tools).

Comment: base64 isn't an image encoding, it is an encoding of binary data as text.  But the binary data for an image could be encoded in many different formats.  What is binary encoding format of the data that you need (e.g. jpg, png, tiff, svg, bmp, etc, etc)?  Why do you need to encode the binary data of an image to base64? How will the encoded base64 data be used?  As a [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)? or something else? Please edit the question to explain.

Comment: I know it's not an image encoding, but I want a lightweight method to save small screenshots as text in a databse (up to 100x100px)

Comment: You don't want to "get the bytes of a clipboard image".  [IMAGE data in the clipboard](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/DataFormat.html#IMAGE) is "A special platform specific image type, such as is commonly used on the clipboard and interoperates widely with other applications. For example, on Mac this might ultimately be a TIFF while on Windows it might be a DIB (device independent bitmap)."  None of which are handled by the JavaFX public image API, so you couldn't do anything with it even if you had the raw data.

Comment: The bytes you get from `getPixels` is just raw color data. It's not in an image file format like PNG or JPEG. You have to encode the pixels to an image file format and _then_ convert it to Base64 (though if you're going to store images in a database, why not just use a blob?).

Comment: Do you want a lossy storage format (e.g. jpg) or lossless (e.g. png)? Any competent database can store [binary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) without base64 encoding. This does seem like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: What you probably want to do is take the JavaFX image returned by the clipboard getImage call, convert it to a BufferedImage, use ImageIO to encode it as a png or jpg, then store that as a blob in your DB. JavaFX then take the binary encoded png or jpg read from the db and display it a JavaFX image.  You don't need a PIxelReader or base64 encoding/decoding for any of that.

Comment: I tried getting the bytes using SwingFXUtils, but SwingFXUtils can't be found. I already imported org.openjfx.javafx-swing in gradle. I also tried manually putting the pixel values in a BufferedImage, but how to I get the byte array from that to save it as a blob?

Comment: If you've applied the [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) then just add `"javafx.swing"` to the `modules` list. If you haven't applied the plugin, then add an `implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-swing:<version>:<classifier>")` dependency (unless something has changed recently, you have to manually specify the platform classifier and transitive dependencies when adding JavaFX to Gradle this way). My answer shows how to insert a blob via JDBC directly. If you're using a JDBC wrapper library or an ORM, look at its documentation for how to do the same.

Comment: Note that even if you forgo `SwingFXUtils` and instead manually "transfer" the pixels from the `Image` to a `BufferedImage`, you'd still get the image file bytes the same way—via `ImageIO`.

Answer (score 3):

The bytes you get from the `getPixels` call are just raw color/pixel data. It is not in an image file format like PNG or JPEG. If you want other software to be able to decode the Base64-encoded image, then you have to first encode the pixels to an actual image file format. For example:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public final class ImageUtils {
    
    private ImageUtils() {}
    
    public static byte[] toImageFile(Image image, String format) {
        var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), format, out);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** `SwingFXUtils` comes from the [`javafx.swing`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.swing/module-summary.html) module.</sup>

Once you have the image file, then you can Base64 encode the bytes:

```java
var image = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getImage();
var bytes = ImageUtils.toImageFile(image, "png");
var base64Str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

<sup>**Note:** PNG is a lossless format. If you want a smaller image file then you can use a lossy format like JPEG.</sup>

But you mention saving this image to a database. If you're going to do that, then I recommend you just store the image as a blob. For example, if you're using JDBC directly:

```java
var image = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getImage();
var bytes = ImageUtils.toImageFile(image, "png");
try (var conn = DriverManager.getConnection("...")) {
    try (var stat = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Foo (image) VALUES (?)")) {
        stat.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        stat.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

You can of course continue using Base64 encoding for other parts of your code if needed.

Comment: Ok but I get this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils, although it's being recognized in the IDE. I haven't used the module-info file yet, do I have to put something there?

Comment: @Maxim If you don't have a module-info file, then your code is not modular.  javafx.swing is a module, it needs to be on the module path even if your code is not modular.  Information on setting up a non-modular project for various IDEs and gradle (which you mentioned you used in another comment) is at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  That shows how to place other JavaFX modules like javafx.controls on the module path and use them.  The javafx.swing module is no different in setup, but you do need to do the setup and use the correct module names & paths for the required modules