# Unable to display image from database to tableview

Tags: javafx

So I'm trying to display images stored in my database as Blob to an image column in table view. All of the other data is displayed well except for those in the image column. I've been struggling for days but still unable to find a solution.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
public void loadPropertyData() throws IOException {
    try {
        Connection connection = OracleConnect.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT id, property, image, price, contact, location, status FROM property" + getProfileName().getText();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        ObservableList<Property> propertyList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String property = resultSet.getString("property");
            Blob imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob("image");
            Image image = null;
            if (imageBlob != null) {
                InputStream is = imageBlob.getBinaryStream();
                image = new Image(is);
            }
            String price = resultSet.getString("price");
            String contact = resultSet.getString("contact");
            String location = resultSet.getString("location");
            String status = resultSet.getString("status");

            Property propertyObj = new Property(id, property, image, price, contact, location, status);
            propertyList.add(propertyObj);
        }

        propertyIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty().asObject());
        propertyColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().propertyProperty());
        propertyImageColumn.setCellValueFactory(col -> col.getValue().imageProperty());
        propertyImageColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
            TableCell<Property, Image> cell = new TableCell<Property, Image>() {
                private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

                {
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                }

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        imageView.setImage(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImage(item);
                        setGraphic(imageView);
                    }
                }
            };

            return cell;
        });
        propertyPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty());
        propertyContactColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().contactProperty());
        propertyLocationColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().locationProperty());
        propertyStatusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().statusProperty());

        propertyTableView.setItems(propertyList);

        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is my Property model

```
Property {
    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty property;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> image;
    private StringProperty price;
    private StringProperty contact;
    private StringProperty location;
    private StringProperty status;

    public Property(int id, String property, Image image, String price, String contact, String location, String status) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.property = new SimpleStringProperty(property);
        this.image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(image);
        this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price);
        this.contact = new SimpleStringProperty(contact);
        this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(location);
        this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public StringProperty propertyProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property.get();
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property.set(property);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image.get();
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image.set(image);
    }

    public StringProperty priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public StringProperty contactProperty() {
        return contact;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact.get();
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact.set(contact);
    }

    public StringProperty locationProperty() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location.get();
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location.set(location);
    }

    public StringProperty statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status.set(status);
    }
}
```

Here is what I used to create table in my database

```
@FXML
private void Signup() {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement createTableStatement = null;
    PreparedStatement createSequenceStatement = null;
    PreparedStatement insertStatement = null;

    try {
        connection = OracleConnect.getConnection();

        // Create table
        String createTableProperty = "CREATE TABLE property" + signupTF.getText() +
                " (" +
                "    id NUMBER," +
                "    property VARCHAR2(50)," +
                "    image BLOB," +
                "    price VARCHAR2(50)," +
                "    contact VARCHAR2(50)," +
                "    location VARCHAR2(50)," +
                "    status VARCHAR2(50)" +
                ")";
        createTableStatement = connection.prepareStatement(createTableProperty);
        createTableStatement.execute();

        // Create sequence
        String createSequenceProperty = "CREATE SEQUENCE property" +
                signupTF.getText() + "_seq " +
                "START WITH 1 " +
                "INCREMENT BY 1 " +
                "MINVALUE 1 " +
                "NOCACHE";
        createSequenceStatement = connection.prepareStatement(createSequenceProperty);
        createSequenceStatement.execute();

        // Insert data
        String insertData = "INSERT INTO property" + signupTF.getText() +
                " (id, property, image, price, contact, location, status)" +
                " VALUES (property" + signupTF.getText() + "_seq.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertData);
        insertStatement.setString(1, "Property Name"); // Set the property name
        insertStatement.setBlob(2, new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/image.jpg"))); // Set the image file
        insertStatement.setString(3, "Price"); // Set the price
        insertStatement.setString(4, "Contact"); // Set the contact
        insertStatement.setString(5, "Location"); // Set the location
        insertStatement.setString(6, "Status"); // Set the status
        insertStatement.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if (e.getErrorCode() == 1400) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter required information");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image file not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (insertStatement != null) {
                insertStatement.close();
            }
            if (createSequenceStatement != null) {
                createSequenceStatement.close();
            }
            if (createTableStatement != null) {
                createTableStatement.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occurred while closing the resources: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the data from my table in the database

[image: data]

Here is what's displayed in the table view

[image: table view]

Comment: I can't find `propertyImageColumn.setCellValueFactory`. I think you must set a _cell value factory_ for each column in the `TableView`. Note that I don't have access to your database so I can't verify whether your code that retrieves data from the database is correct.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to set cell value factory for image datatype. I tried using "propertyImageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getImage());" where method getImage() returns Image datatype and I will get this error " Image cannot be converted to ObservableValue<ImageView>". Can you please help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77512467/loading-and-saving-javafx-image-to-db

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656158/example-javafx-app-to-read-and-write-jpeg-images-to-a-database/75656159#75656159

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536529/save-and-retrieve-image-files-in-mysql-and-javafx/77539003#77539003

Comment: You could also use an [image cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72821525/adding-an-image-into-a-javafx-tableview-column) for better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts with the class that serves as the data model for the `TableView`. In the below code, that class is `ImagItem`. The class must contain an attribute for each column of the `TableView` – which must be an `ObservableValue`. In the below code, there is only one column. Hence class `ImagItem` contains a single attribute. For each attribute you need three methods.

- One that returns the value wrapped by the `ObservableValue`.
- One that assigns the wrapped value.
- One that returns the `ObservableValue`.

Now you just need to define the *cell value factory* and the *cell factory* for the columns of the `TableView`. The *cell value factory* is basically a method that receives a `CellDataFeatures` and returns an `ObservableValue`. In the below code, in the lambda expression that serves as that method, `c` is an instance of `CellDataFeatures<ImagItem, Image>` and its `getValue` method returns an instance of `ImagItem`, so you want that method to return the attribute of `ImagItem` – hence the call to `imageProperty`. Note that the names of the methods in class `ImagItem` are according to the accepted convention.

Finally, the *cell factory* is a method that receives a `TableColumn` and needs to return a `TableCell`. In the below code I have written an anonymous inner class which implicitly extends class `TableCell` and I have overridden method `updateItem`. `TableCell` extends `Labeled` and hence has a *text* property and a *graphic* property. You want your `TableCell` to display an image only, hence, in the below code, I simply wrap the method parameter (`img`) in an `ImageView` and set that as the graphic for the `TableCell`.

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    private static final Path  ROOT = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\USER\\Pictures");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        TableView<ImagItem> table = new TableView<ImagItem>();
        TableColumn<ImagItem, Image> imgCol = new TableColumn<ImagItem, Image>("Image");
        imgCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().imageProperty());
        imgCol.setCellFactory(c -> {
            return new TableCell<ImagItem, Image>() {
                protected void updateItem(Image img, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(img, empty);
                    setText(null);
                    if (img != null  &&  !empty) {
                        ImageView imgVw = new ImageView(img);
                        setGraphic(imgVw);
                    }
                    else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        table.getColumns().add(imgCol);
        ObservableList<ImagItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(getImages());
        table.setItems(items);
        root.getChildren().add(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ImagItem getImage(String name) throws MalformedURLException {
        Path path = ROOT.resolve(name);
        URI uri = path.toUri();
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        Image img = new Image(url.toExternalForm());
        ImagItem ii = new ImagItem(img);
        return ii;
    }

    private List<ImagItem> getImages() throws MalformedURLException {
        List<ImagItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(getImage("284kd.png"));
        list.add(getImage("dynamite.png"));
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class ImagItem {
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Image>  image;

    public ImagItem(Image img) {
        image = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>(this, "image", img);
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image.get();
    }

    public void setImage(Image img) {
        image.set(img);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture:

[image: screen capture]

### Edit

(19 January 2024)
The images were not displayed for you because you probably did not insert them correctly into the database. The below code demonstrates how to update the images in the database (because I assume that you have already inserted them – albeit incorrectly).

For inserting, refer to the accepted answer in this SO question:
[How to write / update Oracle blob in a reliable way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348427/how-to-write-update-oracle-blob-in-a-reliable-way)

I adapted that answer to update the database (because I also initially incorrectly inserted the images into the database).

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UpdImOra {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("ARGS: file, id");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        long len = f.length();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String sql = """
update PROPERTIES
   set IMAGE = ?
 where ID = ?
                """;
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/sid",
                                                           "George",
                                                           "Best");
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, len);
            ps.setInt(2, id);
            int count = ps.executeUpdate();
            String plural = count == 1 ? "" : "s";
            System.out.printf("Updated %d row%s.%n", count, plural);
        }
        catch (IOException | SQLException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Now the images are displayed in the `TableView`.

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OraFxApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Property> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Property, Number> idCol = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().idProperty());
        TableColumn<Property, String> propertyCol = new TableColumn<>("PROPERTY");
        propertyCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().propertyProperty());
        TableColumn<Property, Image> imageCol = new TableColumn<>("IMAGE");
        imageCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().imageProperty());
        imageCol.setCellFactory(c -> {
            return new TableCell<Property, Image>() {
                protected void updateItem(Image img, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(img, empty);
                    setText(null);
                    if (img != null  &&  !empty) {
                        ImageView imgVw = new ImageView(img);
                        setGraphic(imgVw);
                    }
                    else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        TableColumn<Property, Number> priceCol = new TableColumn<>("PRICE");
        priceCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().priceProperty());
        TableColumn<Property, String> contactCol = new TableColumn<>("CONTACT");
        contactCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().contactProperty());
        TableColumn<Property, String> locationCol = new TableColumn<>("LOCATION");
        locationCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().locationProperty());
        TableColumn<Property, String> statusCol = new TableColumn<>("STATUS");
        statusCol.setCellValueFactory(c -> c.getValue().statusProperty());
        ObservableList<TableColumn<Property, ?>> columns = table.getColumns();
        columns.add(idCol);
        columns.add(propertyCol);
        columns.add(imageCol);
        columns.add(priceCol);
        columns.add(contactCol);
        columns.add(locationCol);
        columns.add(statusCol);
        List<Property> list = loadPropertyData();
        ObservableList<Property> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
        table.setItems(items);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private List<Property> loadPropertyData() throws SQLException {
        String sql = """
select ID
      ,PROPERTY
      ,IMAGE
      ,PRICE
      ,CONTACT
      ,LOCATION
      ,STATUS
  from PROPERTIES
                """;
        List<Property> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/sid",
                                                           "George",
                                                           "Best");
             Statement s = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                int iden = rs.getInt(1);
                String prop = rs.getString(2);
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob(3);
                InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
                Image img = new Image(is);
                int cost = rs.getInt(4);
                String liaison = rs.getString(5);
                String place = rs.getString(6);
                String situation = rs.getString(7);
                Property p = new Property(iden, prop, img, cost, liaison, place, situation);
                list.add(p);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Property {
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Number>  id;
    private SimpleStringProperty  property;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Image>  image;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Number>  price;
    private SimpleStringProperty  contact;
    private SimpleStringProperty  location;
    private SimpleStringProperty  status;

    public Property(int iden,
                    String prop,
                    Image  img,
                    int    cost,
                    String liaison,
                    String place,
                    String situation) {
        id = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "id", Integer.valueOf(iden));
        property = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "property", prop);
        image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "image", img);
        price = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "price", Integer.valueOf(cost));
        contact = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "contact", liaison);
        location = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "location", place);
        status = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "status", situation);
    }

    public Number getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(Number iden) {
        id.set(iden);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Number> idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property.get();
    }

    public void setProperty(String prop) {
        property.set(prop);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty propertyProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image.get();
    }

    public void setImage(Image img) {
        image.set(img);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image;
    }

    public Number getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(Number iden) {
        price.set(iden);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Number> priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact.get();
    }

    public void setContact(String prop) {
        contact.set(prop);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty contactProperty() {
        return contact;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location.get();
    }

    public void setLocation(String prop) {
        location.set(prop);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty locationProperty() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public void setStatus(String prop) {
        status.set(prop);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Screen capture:

[image: screen capture 2]

Comment: This seems to retrieve images from available URLs but I'd rather want to populate the image data saved as Blob datatype from the table in database. Is there a way to do that? I just modified the post to contain screenshots of my table in database and table view.

Comment: @phamnguyen I suggest that you first modify your `Property` class and make its attributes `ObservableValue`s - as I explained in my answer. Then add methods for each attribute - as I also explained in my answer. Then change your _cell factory_ and _cell value factory_ definitions - again, as explained in my answer. Then, if you are still having the same problem, we can look at how you retrieve the images from the database.

Comment: I just modified my Property model, wrapped its attributes in `ObservableValue`, added three methods for each attribute and redefined cell value factory and cell factory. The problem still seems to remain as all of the other data is displayed in the table view but image column. I included the edited code in the post so you can see if I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: @phamnguyen Your addition of JavaFX properties to your `Property` class is fine as far as that goes.  I know `Property` is part of your name (as in representing physical property).  However, as long as you have control over naming, I don't suggest naming your own class `Property` in a JavaFX application, because it can easily get confused with JavaFX properties.  Just choose some other name.

Comment: @phamnguyen As you continue to experience problems, provide a [mcve].  That will allow somebody to reproduce your issue by just copying and pasting your code and running it with no change or addition.  You can't expect to get debug assistance for code that nobody else can run.   As an answerer will not have your database, stub out *all* of the database code, and use hardcoded data instead.

Comment: @jewelsea I'm sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for letting me know. I just added the method I used to create and insert data into table. I don't know if it's useful though, and I also have no idea how to make it minimal so everyone can simply copy and paste since I created the table view in SceneBuilder. I will try my best to modify my example as soon as I can. I also realized the problem lies in the way I retrieve the images from the database. Please let me know what else I should provide in order to clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

Populates a database with data, sourcing some test images from URLs, then retrieves the data from the database and displays it in a JavaFX Table.

[image: sour mikan]

*module-info.java*

```
module org.example.h2image {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires java.sql;

    exports org.example.h2image;
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2image</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>h2image</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*ImageTableApplication.java*

```
package org.example.h2image;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class ImageTableApplication extends Application {
    private final PropertyDao propertyDao = new PropertyDao();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        propertyDao.createDB();
        propertyDao.populateDB();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<PropertyInfo> tableView = new TableView<>(
                propertyDao.findProperties()
        );
        tableView.setPrefSize(600, 350);
        tableView.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px");

        TableColumn<PropertyInfo, Integer> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty().asObject());

        TableColumn<PropertyInfo, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Property");
        nameColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<PropertyInfo, Image> imageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Image");
        imageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().imageProperty());
        imageColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new ImageCell<>());

        TableColumn<PropertyInfo, String> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty());

        TableColumn<PropertyInfo, String> locationColumn = new TableColumn<>("Location");
        locationColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
        locationColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().locationProperty());

        TableColumn<PropertyInfo, String> statusColumn = new TableColumn<>("Status");
        statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().statusProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().setAll(
                List.of(
                        idColumn,
                        nameColumn,
                        imageColumn,
                        priceColumn,
                        locationColumn,
                        statusColumn
                )
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tableView));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

*ImageCell.java*

```
package org.example.h2image;

import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

class ImageCell<S> extends TableCell<S, Image> {
    private final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

    public ImageCell() {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            imageView.setImage(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            imageView.setImage(item);
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

*PropertyInfo.java*

```
package org.example.h2image;

import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class PropertyInfo {
    private final IntegerProperty id;
    private final StringProperty name;
    private final ObjectProperty<Image> image;
    private final StringProperty price;
    private final StringProperty contact;
    private final StringProperty location;
    private final StringProperty status;

    public PropertyInfo(int id, String name, Image image, String price, String contact, String location, String status) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(image);
        this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price);
        this.contact = new SimpleStringProperty(contact);
        this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(location);
        this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image.get();
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image.set(image);
    }

    public StringProperty priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public StringProperty contactProperty() {
        return contact;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact.get();
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact.set(contact);
    }

    public StringProperty locationProperty() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location.get();
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location.set(location);
    }

    public StringProperty statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status.set(status);
    }
}
```

*PropertyDao.java*

```
package org.example.h2image;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.*;

public class PropertyDao {
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
    private static final String CREATE_PROPERTY_TABLE_DDL = // language=SQL
            """
            CREATE TABLE property
            ( 
                id NUMBER, 
                property VARCHAR2(50), 
                image BLOB, 
                price VARCHAR2(50), 
                contact VARCHAR2(50), 
                location VARCHAR2(50), 
                status VARCHAR2(50) 
            );
            """;
    private static final String CREATE_PROPERTY_SEQ_DDL = // language=SQL
            """
            CREATE SEQUENCE property_seq
            START WITH 1
            INCREMENT BY 1
            MINVALUE 1;
            """;
    private static final String INSERT_PROPERTY_SQL = // language=SQL
            """
            INSERT INTO property
              (id, property, image, price, contact, location, status)
            VALUES 
              ((select next value for property_seq), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
            """;

    private static final String FIND_PROPERTY_SQL = // language=SQL
            """
            SELECT id, property, image, price, contact, location, status FROM property
            """;

    public void createDB() {
        try (
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
                PreparedStatement createTableStatement = connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_PROPERTY_TABLE_DDL);
                PreparedStatement createSequenceStatement = connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_PROPERTY_SEQ_DDL);
        ) {
            createTableStatement.execute();
            createSequenceStatement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void populateDB() {
        try (
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
                PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_PROPERTY_SQL)
        ) {
            int i = 0;
            for (PropertyInfo propertyInfo: TestData.TEST_PROPERTIES) {
                try (InputStream imageInputStream = new URI(TestData.TEST_IMAGE_LOCS.get(i)).toURL().openStream()) {
                    insertStatement.setString(1, propertyInfo.getName());
                    insertStatement.setBlob(2, imageInputStream);
                    insertStatement.setString(3, propertyInfo.getPrice());
                    insertStatement.setString(4, propertyInfo.getContact());
                    insertStatement.setString(5, propertyInfo.getLocation());
                    insertStatement.setString(6, propertyInfo.getStatus());
                    insertStatement.execute();

                    i++;
                } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ObservableList<PropertyInfo> findProperties() {
        try (
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(FIND_PROPERTY_SQL);
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()
        ) {
            ObservableList<PropertyInfo> propertyList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                String property = resultSet.getString("property");
                Blob imageBlob = resultSet.getBlob("image");
                Image image = null;
                if (imageBlob != null) {
                    InputStream is = imageBlob.getBinaryStream();
                    image = new Image(is);
                }
                String price = resultSet.getString("price");
                String contact = resultSet.getString("contact");
                String location = resultSet.getString("location");
                String status = resultSet.getString("status");

                PropertyInfo propertyObj = new PropertyInfo(id, property, image, price, contact, location, status);
                propertyList.add(propertyObj);
            }

            return propertyList;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }
}
```

*TestData.java*

```
package org.example.h2image;

import java.util.List;

public class TestData {
    public static final List<PropertyInfo> TEST_PROPERTIES = List.of(
            new PropertyInfo(
                    1,
                    "Mikan",
                    null,
                    "$2.00",
                    "The demon girl next door",
                    "Tokyo",
                    "Very Sour"
            ),
            new PropertyInfo(
                    2,
                    "Lemon",
                    null,
                    "$1.00",
                    "Mami Tomoe",
                    "Osaka",
                    "Very Sweet"
            )
    );
    public static final List<String> TEST_IMAGE_LOCS = List.of(
            "https://www.iconarchive.com/download/i107438/google/noto-emoji-food-drink/32344-tangerine.128.png",
            "https://www.iconarchive.com/download/i107439/google/noto-emoji-food-drink/32345-lemon.128.png"
    );
}
```

*Test Images*

[image: mikan]
[image: lemon]